# Collect strings into single array inside forEach

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How to collect string results into single array inside for Each loop

```
<ul>
    <li data-tag="two"></li>
    <li data-tag="three"></li>
    <li data-tag="four"></li>
    <li data-tag="five"></li>
</ul>
<button id="ev">Click</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var elem = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul > li'));

document.getElementById('ev').addEventListener('click', function(ev){

    elem.forEach( function(el,i) {
        var ar = ["one"];
        var tags = el.getAttribute('data-tag');

        ar.push(tags);
    });

});
```

Result:

```
["one", "two"]
["one", "three"]
["one", "four"]
["one", "five"]
```

Expecting result:

```
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

Comment: Move `var ar = ["one"];` outside of the loop

Comment: Also to get data attribute use, `el.dataSet.tag`

Comment: @Tushar, yep, but dataset  IE11+, and litle bit slower than getAttribute ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)). thanks btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `arr` before `forEach`

```js
var elem = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul > li'));

document.getElementById('ev').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    var ar = ["one"];
  
    elem.forEach( function(el,i) {
        var tags = el.getAttribute('data-tag');
        ar.push(tags);
    });
  
    console.log(ar);
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li data-tag="two"></li>
    <li data-tag="three"></li>
    <li data-tag="four"></li>
    <li data-tag="five"></li>
</ul>
<button id="ev">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The probem is that you're declaring `ar` variable inside the forEach function, which overwrites the values instead of pushing them into your array.

```js
var ar = ['one'];
elem.forEach( function(el,i) {
  var tags = el.getAttribute('data-tag');

  ar.push(tags);
});
```